# How to use Umax Astra 5600 in Windows 7 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, scanner

I have a Umax Astra 5600 Scanner. I lost my PC in an accident while moving. Now I have a HP Pavilion g4 with Windows 7 (64 bit). I tried using my scanner on it but the scanner is not even recognised on windows. I tried loading drivers but those were WinXP drivers and are not working with Windows.
It is very good scanner and will be happy to keep working on It. Please guide me. It works on a friends system that uses WinXP.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. My Umax Astra 5600 scanner used to run perfectly on Windows XP, but later after upgrading to Windows 7 my scanner failed to connect to my PC. After searching the web (various blogs, questions & answers) for a solution i came across a suggestion to install the driver of the scanner in compatible mode for win2000 in the win7 OS and then run the program too in compatible mode. The suggestion helped me and solved my problem.
I installed the driver of the scanner from the disc that was supplied with the scanner in my PC (OS Win7) in compatible mode for Win2000 and then ran the program (i.e. Hotkeys) in compatible mode for Win XP and my scanner got connected to my PC.
Hope your problem too gets solved.
Do let me know if my suggestion was fruitful.